# How to add/pass multiple values to Intent object?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

i have two EditText objects in my first activity. i want both their values when i go to the next activity.
Lets assume the EditText objects are inp1, inp2 and they can only accept numbers.
please mention how i can add their values to int Intent object and how i will extract their values in my next activity's .java file.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: kindly do google first before posting :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, your code will look like,

Sender Side:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName1", intValue1);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName2", intValue2);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Receiver Side:

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue1 = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName1", 0);
 int intValue2 = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName2", 0);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, Second.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("value1",String.valueof(inp1.getText().toString()));
extras.putString("value2",String.valueof(inp2.getText().toString()));
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your second Activity **onCreate()**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String value1 = extras.getString("value1");
String value2 = extras.getString("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make thing easier and reusable you can make your own intent like this

```java
public class MyIntent extent Intent{
    private static final String FIRST_VALUE;
    private static final String SECOND_VALUE;

    public MyIntent(Context context, String firstValue, String secondValue){
        super(context,MySecondActivity.class);
        putExtra(FIRST_VALUE, firstValue);
        putExtra(SECOND_VALUE, secondValue);
    }

    public String getFirstValue(){
        getStringExtra(FIRST_VALUE);
    }

    public String getSecondValue(){
        getStringExtra(SECOND_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Sender:

```java
startActivity(new MyIntent(this,"FirstString", "SecondString"));
```

Receiver Side:

```java
MyIntent myIntent = (MyIntent)getIntent();
String firstValue  = myIntent.getFirstValue();
String secondValue = myIntent.getSecondValue();
```